# mesh faces permanently highlighted?

Tags: selection-tools, subdivision-surface

[image]

Very new to blender, trying to touch up a file for eventual 3d printing of a helmet. I was selectively blending areas of the obj file, and then for some reason the selection of faces I was currently trying *not* to smooth with my subdivision surface modified (highlighted in the pink/maroon on the right side of the picture) became permanently highlighted, as if selected. I thought I may have had to do with the subdivision surface modifier, so I deleted it, but to no avail.

any help? its very hard to work with, as it obscured my view of the model.

Comment: Pink edges are creased edges (with crease >-1). It's not an highlight, but an indication of a property. Which are the "maroon" elements you are mentioning?

Answer (score 1):

### Crease indicators

Pink colored edges in Blender is used to show edges that have a [crease](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/glossary/index.html?highlight=crease) greater than the default value (which is -1). As written in the manual's page, crease is:

> ...used to define the sharpness of edges in subdivision surface meshes.

You can set the crease of the selected edges by pressing the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> shortcut and enter a numeric value. Here's a few examples of possible values:

- -1 - edge doesn't have any sharpness (no purple color)
- +0 - edge have an average sharpness (dark purple color)
- +1 - edge is sharp (bright purple color)

You can also control the visibility setting of this overlay (an many other such as seams or sharp edges...) in the Mesh Display panel of the Properties bar.

[image]